# Gaps between Gaussian primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gaussian-integers

I was reading about Gaussian primes when I came across an article on bounded gaps and distance between such numbers. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is not a totally ordered set, I find it strange to talk about "prime gaps" and "distances" between Gaussian numbers. In particular:

- Since it is not possible to define an operator $<$ (or $>$) such that $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C}: a<b$, how is possible to talk about a Gaussian prime being "smaller" or "larger" than another one, or about a "distance" between consecutive Gaussian primes? Is this somehow related to geometric distances between lattice points in $\mathbb{C}$?
- What is the current research on "distances between Gaussian primes" and is it related in some manner to gaps between primes in $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: You can order them by their norm: two different Gaussian primes can't have the same norm (because the prime decomposition of the norm is unique up to units).

Comment: @ProfessorVector Are you sure? For example, if $a^2+b^2, a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then both $a+bi$ and $b+ai$ are different Gaussian primes with same norm

Comment: @Pickle Well, yes, the conjugate has the same norm, and $b+ai=i(a-bi).$

Comment: @ProfessorVector But aren't those two different Gaussian primes?

Comment: @Pickle curiously I did a similar question some time ago, just in case, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1725867/is-there-a-standard-way-of-defining-a-total-order-between-gaussian-primes

Comment: @iadvd I also read the paper mentioned in your question :) How is your paper going with the Euler Lucky numbers?

Comment: @Pickle do you mean this topic?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859996/a-function-can-provide-the-complete-set-of-euler-primes-via-a-mills-like-consta     well, I am trying to publish not the "Euler Lucky numbers" constant itself, but the way of calculating that constant as a more generic pattern (still on it, and it will take time to find an appropriated publisher for it, but still fighting for it).

Comment: @iadvd Sounds interesting. Will you try submitting it to number theory journals or more general publishers?

Comment: @Pickle to journals that are publishing topics on number theory but not specifically number theory journals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62972/discussion-between-pickle-and-iadvd).